# AWS security groups not working as expected

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-security-group

I am not able to understand the concept of AWS "Security groups being stateful". I was playing with the security group rules, where I opened an inbound traffic on port 80 and there are no rules in outbound.

[image: Outbound rules]

[image: Inbound rules]

Technically, my understand is when we open an inbound rule , outbound is also automatically opened. When I go to Ec2 instance and do yum update -y, it's hanging up. But when I add traffic for all ports in outbound, yum update is working fine.

Help my understanding.

Comment: Your SSH session is working correctly due to the stateful nature of security rules. But doing something on the instance that is NOT returning to your SSH request (eg downloading from the Internet) is considered a new outbound connection. It is therefore denied.

Answer (score 2):

Security groups are stateful in a sense that if traffic is allowed one way, then response traffic is allowed in opposite way.

In your case when you run `yum update` it needs to reach repos via HTTP(s) on port 80 first. Since you didn't allow this outbound traffic, it's not gonna work. However if someone requested your instance on port 80, response from your machine would've gone through.

So it's not "outbound traffic is allowed if I allowed inbound", you need to allow whichever traffic comes first. In your case it's outbound.

Answer (score 1):

When a web browser connects to your web server there are two ports in play on the connection: port 80 on your web server and some high-numbered ephemeral port like 49152 on the client. A request is sent from client:49152 to server:80. These ip-address:port tuples are called sockets. The response from the web server has to travel from server:80 back to client:49152.

The 'stateful' nature of AWS Security Groups means that some state is remembered for later use. That state includes the combination of client:49152 and server:80 sockets that make up a valid TCP connection. If a request is received on server:80 from client:49152, then the response to client:49152 will be allowed from server:80 without requiring you to configure any additional outbound firewall rules.

You do not, for example, have to create a second rule allowing outbound communications from your server on port 80 to the client on port 49152. That second rule is implicit because of the stateful nature of Security Groups. It would actually be very difficult for you to create this rule if it were not implicit, because the client's port number is ephemeral and can be any one of a wide range of numbers, and can be a different number from one connection to the next. You would have no idea in advance what port number it would be, so the only thing you could do here, if this were not stateful, would be to open up a wide range of ports in an outbound firewall rule.

EC2/VPC also has the concept of [Network ACLs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/vpc-network-acls.html). These are stateless firewall rules. In this case, both inbound and outbound rules are required for traffic to flow both ways.